# Apple In App Purchase Auto Renewal Subscriptions Payment not deducted but expires_date within latest_receipt_info has been increased

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have added IAP "Auto Renewal Subscriptions" in my iOS app. and after trail period my subscription has been extends but subscription amount did not deducted from my account.

```
What happened why expires_date has been extend and subscription amount did not deducted from user.

User using app from last 3 days without paying amount of Auto renewal subscription. 

It's live application and in receipt verification i am parsing "expires_date" using "buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt".

Is any buddy can help me?
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then your subscription auto-renewed after the trial but your account wasn't billed for that? I assume your app isn't released yet and you have tested the purchase with a debug build. Payments in debug builds are handled in a different environment (sandbox) than payments in apps downloaded from the App Store. Payments in the sandbox are completely free and therefore there was no reason to bill your account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But for other users payment is deducted and in "App Analytics Data" it's showing sale $41.

Comment: Have those users downloaded the app from the App Store?

Comment: yes, it have more then 50 users

Comment: Did you bought the subscription (you're writing in your question) in an XCode build of your app or in the App Store version?

Comment: No, i have downloaded latest version of app from App Store. and in receipt verification parsing "expires_date" using "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please wait at list 4-5 days. Apple will deduct your subscription amount. some times apple process takes time.